How to include Font Awesome icons into 'menu_icon' from register_post_type() function - wp admin?
I would like to use font awesome icons instead of dashicons inside menu_icons argument of register_post_type() function or for add_menu_page() icon argument.
I have found another page that suggest to use fa fa- icons like that :
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-fa fa-layer-group',
But this syntaxe should be wrong because Font Awesome requires fa-solid, fa-regular or fa-brands.
Then the author suggest to filter sanitize_html_class to implement this syntaxe.
What I have done :
I added a folder inside my wordpress plugin named "Awesome".
All.css is the main css file that contains all icons.
Then I enqueue font Awesome :
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }
define('STMPOSTTYPE', __FILE__);
function stm_new_post_type() {
        wp_enqueue_style('stm-new-post-type-css', plugins_url('', STMPOSTTYPE) . '/new-post-type.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('awesome', plugins_url('', STMPOSTTYPE) . '/Awesome/all.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('stm-new-post-type-js', plugins_url('', STMPOSTTYPE) . '/new-post-type.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
 }

In my arguments I added menu_icons like that:
$args = array(
   'labels' => $labels,
   'public' => true,
   'show_in_menu' => true,
   'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-fa fa-solid fa-layer-group',
   'has_archive' => true
);

And I used the script from another page (@smarteist):
add_filter( 'sanitize_html_class', function ( $sanitized, $class, $fallback ) {

    if ( strpos( $class, 'fa' )
         || strpos( $class, 'fas' )
         || strpos( $class, 'fal' )
         || strpos( $class, 'fab' )
         || strpos( $class, 'far' )
    ) {
        $class = str_replace( 'dashicons-', '', $class );

        return $class;

    }

    return $sanitized;

}, 0, 3 );

Currently I have no icon with this script.

it would be much easier, and much more performant, to go to fontawesome, find the icon you want, and download its SVG. This sidesteps all the problems you've encountered, and simplifies the problem enormously to "how do I specify a custom image URL for the menu icon" which is super easy to do compared to what you're asking ( https://fontawesome.com/icons/layer-group?f=classic&s=solid )

I understand, but I like to learn and find solutions to save time later and not have to download icons one by one every time I need a new one!
I've unblocked part of my problem. The font awesome code writes well in the div displaying the icon like this 'fa-solid fa-layer-group' but the icon doesn't load at the moment.
The filter allows you to write 'dashicons-fa-solid fa-layer-group' in the menu-icons argument. I'm still looking. Probably the path to ttf and woff2 is wrong.

understood, for others reading you can download the entire fontawesome and the SVGs are in a folder with the same names. re: the path, how is STMPOSTTYPE being defined/populated? The first parameter of plugins_url is meant to be the subpath of the asset but you're appending the subpath to the result, e.g. plugins_url('', STMPOSTTYPE) . '/Awesome/all.css' should instead be plugins_url( '/Awesome/all.css', STMPOSTTYPE ). If plugins_url is the issue then it would show in the browser JS error console

So, my plugins_url is correct. (I'm going to specify my code in my question)  The problem come from dashicons generated by dashicons- class , apparently  the only class supported by wordpress (otherwise wp converted to url), that add css pseudo-element :before which contain font-family:dashicons;.

I haven't found any solution to entirely convert dashicons- class automatically generated into fas fa-....
Having always used fa-solid or fa-regular I didn't know you could shorten with fas and far.
My mistake
So I bypassed the style font-family:dashicons; adding:
div.wp-menu-image.dashicons-before[class*="fa"]::before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free" !important;
}

In theory [class*="fa"] include fa, fas, fab and far class.
The Font Awesome Icon display correctly.
